# Passing a javascript parameter from an outer scope to an anonymous callback function

Tags: javascript, facebook, asynchronous, anonymous-function

Consider the following

```
function firstFunction() {
  for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    FB.api(apiPath,function(response) {
      secondFunction(response,i);
  });
}

function secondFunction(response,num) {
  alert(num);
}
```

I wanted the secondFunction to be called asynchronously 10 times, each time receiving a different number in num.
Instead, secondFunction is called 10 times and in all of them num is 10.

Can someone explain to me why it is not passed like i expect and how i can fix it to act like i expect ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your synchronous `for` loop increments `i` all the way to 10 before the first `FB.api` async callback executes.

Like this:

```
function firstFunction() {
  for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i2) {
      FB.api(apiPath,function(response) {
        secondFunction(response, i2);
      });
    })(i);
  }
}
```

The fix puts the async function call into its own function so that `i` can be passed in as a parameter, capturing the value of `i` at the time of the call, rather than when the async callback occurs.

Comment: thanks ... its always confusing that the secondFunction is called with the params which are evaluated only *at the time the FB.api async funcntion returns*

Answer (score 0):

This is because the second function is only called when the server returns a response on the asynchronous call and the loop continues running, by the time the server responds the var I is already at 10.

To fix it, you need tone able to pass the i variable into the first api and then have it passed to the second So you can referenced.

You may have to refactor the method to get them to loop 10 times